# When I use MainWindow.hide() funtion, it gives me an error stating MainWindow is not defined but same MainWindow works in setupUI and retranslateUI

Tags: mysql, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am fairly new  to PyQt5. So here, I am trying to work on a project in which first window in login page dialog window. So if password entered are correct it will open another window.

```
def login(self):
    eid=self.lineEdit.text()
    epass=self.lineEdit_2.text()
    
    if eid==idd and epass==passs:
        from BloodBank import Ui_MainWindow
        self.MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.MainWindow)
        LoginPage.hide()
        self.MainWindow.show()
    else:
        self.msgdlg("Wrong ID or Password!")
```

In this Window, from title bar menu action, I tried to attach yet another window, which when opened, current window become hidden. For this I wrote following code:

```
def menu(self,action):
    txt=(action.text())
    if txt=="Blood":
        try:
            from Blood import Ui_MainWindow
            self.MainWindow1 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self.MainWindow1)
            MainWindow.hide()
            self.ui.updatelist()
            self.MainWindow1.show()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Now, When I run above code without MainWindow.hide() it run perfectly fine. But as soon as I feed MainWindow.hide() it gives following error.

> name 'MainWindow' is not defined

When I try same .hide() funtion with login page, it works.
What do I need to do so I can hide my window?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit unclear, but i think it should be `self.MainWindow.hide()` because we are trying to **hide** our parent widget.

**Edit**

Try `self.hide()` in the *bloodbank* file instead of `MainWindow.hide()` I am assuming that in the file *bloodbank* you have your *mainwindow*.

Here is the problem, you have two files the **Login File** which consists of the *loginpage* and the **bloodbank file**.

when you created a the instance of `self.MainWindow` it is only in the `namespace` of the *loginpage*.

And you try to open a another window from this file (which is the 2nd part of your code). `MainWindow` instance is not present because you have defined (instantiated) in another file (*login page*).

Comment: I tried it but then it will give this error:'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'MainWindow'

Comment: About unclear code, I can explain it. I have posted function which is connected to my pushbutton. Now in my first code, I am checking if entered id and password is correct. If correct it will open another window from class imported from my second file which is "BloodBank". Now 2nd code is from "Bloodbank" file. In this I am trying to open yet another window from menu action. But what i want is to hide my current window.

Comment: When I run my project from directly from Bloodbank file without login file. It works fine with MainWindow.hide(). But when I run  Login Page which in turn opens BloodBank file which then open another window,my code stuck on MainWindow.hide(). Without MainWindow.hide(), everything works fine but my window remains open